# Парсинг внутренних ссылок сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Необходимо сделать парсер внутренних ссылок на сайт, т.е. я задаю url и должен получить ссылки на этот же сайт, которые на данной странице и пройти все ссылки и там тоже собрать ссылки. Я написал код, но получаю лишние ссылки, такие как: "#" или "номер телефона". Мой код:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = 'http://101-rosa.ru'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
urls = [link['href'] for link in soup if link.get('href')]


for u in urls:
    nu = u.contents(0)
    r = requests.get(nu)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', 
parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
    url = [link['href'] for link in soup2 if link.get('href')]
    nu = urlparse(url)
    if nu.netloc == 'www.http://101-rosa.ru:80' and urls.count(url) == 0:
        urls.append(url)


print(len(urls))
print(urls)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно исключить из рассмотрения номера телефонов и внутристраничные ссылки, проверив, начинается ли ссылка со строки `#` или `tel:`. Проверка выглядит примерно так:

```
if not link.startswith('#') and not link.startswith('tel:'):
    // обрабатываем ссылку
```

Полный код:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

DOMAIN = '101-rosa.ru'
HOST = 'http://' + DOMAIN
FORBIDDEN_PREFIXES = ['#', 'tel:', 'mailto:']
links = set()  # множество всех ссылок


def add_all_links_recursive(url, maxdepth=1):
    # print('{:>5}'.format(len(links)), url[len(HOST):])
    # извлекает все ссылки из указанного `url`
    # и рекурсивно обрабатывает их
    # глубина рекурсии не более `maxdepth`

    # список ссылок, от которых в конце мы рекурсивно запустимся
    links_to_handle_recursive = []

    # получаем html код страницы
    request = requests.get(url)
    # парсим его с помощью BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')
    # рассматриваем все теги <a>
    for tag_a in soup.find_all('a'):
        # получаем ссылку, соответствующую тегу
        link = tag_a['href']
        # если ссылка не начинается с одного из запрещённых префиксов
        if all(not link.startswith(prefix) for prefix in FORBIDDEN_PREFIXES):
            # проверяем, является ли ссылка относительной
            # например, `/oplata` --- это относительная ссылка
            # `http://101-rosa.ru/oplata` --- это абсолютная ссылка
            if link.startswith('/') and not link.startswith('//'):
                # преобразуем относительную ссылку в абсолютную
                link = HOST + link
            # проверяем, что ссылка ведёт на нужный домен
            # и что мы ещё не обрабатывали такую ссылку
            if urlparse(link).netloc == DOMAIN and link not in links:
                links.add(link)
                links_to_handle_recursive.append(link)

    if maxdepth > 0:
        for link in links_to_handle_recursive:
            add_all_links_recursive(link, maxdepth=maxdepth - 1)

def main():
    add_all_links_recursive(HOST + '/')
    for link in links:
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```