# Не работает парсер ссылок

Tags: python

Взял код отсюда: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716614/Парсинг-внутренних-ссылок-сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716614/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)

Проблема заключается в том что при запуске скрипта он просто молча зависает в консоли

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

URL = 'https://ostrovok.ru/hotel/russia/?q=153'
HOST = 'https://ostrovok.ru'
links = set()  # множество всех ссылок


def add_all_links_recursive(URL, maxdepth=1):
    # print('{:>5}'.format(len(links)), url[len(HOST):])
    # извлекает все ссылки из указанного `url`
    # и рекурсивно обрабатывает их
    # глубина рекурсии не более `maxdepth`

    # список ссылок, от которых в конце мы рекурсивно запустимся
    links_to_handle_recursive = []

    # получаем html код страницы
    request = requests.get(URL)
    # парсим его с помощью BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')
    # рассматриваем все теги <a>
    for tag_a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        # получаем ссылку, соответствующую тегу
        link = tag_a['href']
        if link.startswith('/hotel/russia') and not link.startswith('/hotel/russia/p'):
            if link.startswith('/') and not link.startswith('//'):
                # преобразуем относительную ссылку в абсолютную
                link = HOST + link
                # проверяем, что ссылка ведёт на нужный домен
                # и что мы ещё не обрабатывали такую ссылку
            if link not in links:
                links.add(link)
                links_to_handle_recursive.append(link)

    if maxdepth > 0:
        for link in links_to_handle_recursive:
            add_all_links_recursive(link, maxdepth=maxdepth - 1)

def main():
    add_all_links_recursive(URL)
    for link in links:
        print(link)
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Профилированием занимались? Если вы не захотели потратить время чтобы задебажить код, то почему остальные должны его запускать и искать неточность в нем. Поставьте print на каждой строке, и выводите данные из всевозможных переменных, запустите код в дебаг режиме и проследите что делается в каждой строке. Это будет еще и вам полезно, поймете как код работает и найдете неточность в коде, которая вам мешает.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. Скорее всего там замкнутый круг из ссылок.
Например в `ostrovok.ru` ссылка на `https://ostrovok.ru/hotel/russia/?q=153` а в нем на `ostrovok.ru` - вот и зависает